# Global Variable Not updating in all Phaser States

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io, phaser-framework

On the `helm` state, when you set the warp factor and press the engage button, it calls `engage` which emits the necessary data. The server receives this, determines whether or not inertial dampeners are active then either emits `'warpFailed'` or updates the warp factor. In `app.js` the server emit is received and `globalGame.warpFailed` is updated. In the `captain` state, `globalGame.warpFailed` is checked.

The issue is that in the `helm` state, `globalGame.warpFailed` is logged correctly to the console and reflects the correct state. In `captain` state, it constantly logs `false` regardless of what the value actually is.

I'm honestly not even sure what code to show but here's everything I can think of:

server.js:

```
socket.on('warp', function (data) {
    if (serverGameData.helm.inertDampeners) {
        socket.emit('warpFailed');
    } else {
        serverGameData.helm.warpFactor = data.helm.warpFactor;
    }
});
```

app.js

```
var socket = io(),
    globalGame = {
        sfx: {
            effects: null,
            intro: null,
            menuBoot: null,
            impulse: null,
            warp: null
        },
        warpFailed: false
    }

/* LOTS OF IRRELEVANT CODE HERE - NONE OF WHICH TOUCHES THE ABOVE DECALRED */

socket.on('warpFailed', function () {
    globalGame.warpFailed = true;
});
```

helm state (this is the ONLY place it is referenced in this state and this logs the changing value to the console correctly):

```
update() {
    console.log(globalGame.warpFailed);
}

engage() {
// Called by a button press in this state
    globalGame.sfx.effects.play("launch_02", 1);
    socket.emit('warp', {
        helm: {
            warpFactor: this.warpNum
        }
    });
}
```

captain state (this is also the ONLY place it is referenced in this state. It constantly logs `false` to the console.):

```
update() {
    console.log(globalGame.warpFailed);
}
```

Is there some logic error I'm making here or something obvious I'm missing? I have checked and re-checked and these are the ONLY areas that access or have anything to do with `globalGame.warpFailed`.

Comment: I'm almost certain it has to do with setting the value inside an anonymous function and the JavaScript scoping of variables. Don't know the solution though, sorry.

Comment: Are you declaring your `globalGame` var inside the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the issue:

```
socket.on('warp', function (data) {
    if (serverGameData.helm.inertDampeners) {
        socket.emit('warpFailed'); // <---- RIGHT HERE
    } else {
        serverGameData.helm.warpFactor = data.helm.warpFactor;
    }
});
```

The `warp` emit was coming from the helm state which is a unique socket. Because of this, the response was only being emitted to that specific socket. I changed `socket.emit('warpFailed')` to `io.emit('warpFailed')` and it is successfully emitted to all sockets as intended.